# Convert a JavaBean to key/value Map with nested name using commons-beans BeanUtils

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils

I start using BeanUtils to convert a Properties files to a JavaBean.
Using BeanUtils.populate, I'm able to do this nicely. But I can achieve the retro conversion from the JavaBean to the Map correctly (only simple values are store).

See this sample based on the Employee Class form the BeanUtils documentation.

```
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Employee {

    private Map<String, Address> addressMap = new HashMap<String, Address>();
    private List<Employee> subordinateList = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Address getAddress(String type) {
        if (!addressMap.containsKey(type)) {
            addressMap.put(type, new Address());
        }

        return addressMap.get(type);
    }

    public void setAddress(String type, Address address) {
        addressMap.put(type, address);
    }

    public Employee getSubordinate(int index) {
        if (subordinateList.size() <= index) {
            subordinateList.add(new Employee());
        }

        return subordinateList.get(index);
    }

    public void setSubordinate(int index, Employee subordinate) {
        subordinateList.add(index, subordinate);
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public class Address {
        private String city;
        private String street;
        private int number;

        public String getCity() {
            return city;
        }

        public void setCity(String city) {
            this.city = city;
        }

        public String getStreet() {
            return street;
        }

        public void setStreet(String street) {
            this.street = street;
        }

        public int getNumber() {
            return number;
        }

        public void setNumber(int number) {
            this.number = number;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> map = new TreeMap<String, Object>();

        map.put("firstName", "MyfirstName");
        map.put("lastName", "MylastName");
        map.put("address(pro).city", "MyProCity");
        map.put("address(pro).street", "MyProStreet");
        map.put("address(pro).number", 22);

        map.put("subordinate[1].firstName", "Sub1FirstName");
        map.put("subordinate[1].lastName", "Sub1LastName");

        map.put("address(perso).city", "MyPersoCity");
        map.put("address(perso).street", "MyPersoStreet");
        map.put("address(perso).number", 2);

        map.put("subordinate[0].firstName", "Sub0FirstName");
        map.put("subordinate[0].lastName", "Sub0LastName");


        Employee employee = new Employee();
        BeanUtils.populate(employee, map);

        System.out.println(employee.getFirstName());
        System.out.println(employee.getLastName());

        System.out.println(employee.getAddress("pro").city);
        System.out.println(employee.getAddress("pro").street);
        System.out.println(employee.getAddress("pro").number);

        System.out.println(employee.getAddress("perso").city);
        System.out.println(employee.getAddress("perso").street);
        System.out.println(employee.getAddress("perso").number);

        System.out.println(employee.getSubordinate(0).firstName);
        System.out.println(employee.getSubordinate(0).lastName);

        System.out.println(employee.getSubordinate(1).firstName);
        System.out.println(employee.getSubordinate(1).lastName);

        Map<String, Object> map2 = BeanUtils.describe(employee);

        System.out.println("----------------");

        System.out.println(map2);


    }

}
```

The result :

```
MyfirstName
MylastName
MyProCity
MyProStreet
22
MyPersoCity
MyPersoStreet
2
Sub0FirstName
Sub0LastName
Sub1FirstName
Sub1LastName
----------------
{lastName=MylastName, class=class Employee, firstName=MyfirstName}
```

What am I missing so that the map2 stores actually keys like "address(pro).city" or "subordinate[1].firstName" using the BeanUtils.describe method ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I find a way to solve this. First of all, I need to retrieve every nested propertyName based on my current bean instance, and this recursively. So I've wrote a simple method to do this :

```
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils;
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

import java.beans.PropertyDescriptor;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class MyPropertyUtils {

    public List<String> listNestedPropertyName(Object objectSource) throws Exception {
        List<String> nodeNameList = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom(objectSource.getClass())) {
            nodeNameList.add(objectSource.toString());
            return nodeNameList;
        }

        PropertyDescriptor[] propertyDescriptors = PropertyUtils.getPropertyDescriptors(objectSource.getClass());

        for (PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor : propertyDescriptors) {

            Method method = propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod();
            if (propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod() == null) {
                continue;
            }

            if (method.getGenericParameterTypes().length > 0) {
                continue;
            }

            String name = propertyDescriptor.getName();

            Object value = method.invoke(objectSource);

            if (value == null) {
                continue;
            }

            if (Map.class.isAssignableFrom(value.getClass())) { // Mapped name
                Map map = ((Map) value);
                name = StringUtils.substringBeforeLast(name, "Map");

                for (Object key : map.keySet()) {
                    String mappedName = name + "(" + key.toString() + ")";
                    List<String> nestedNames = listNestedPropertyName(map.get(key));

                    for (String nestedName : nestedNames) {
                        nodeNameList.add(mappedName + "." + nestedName);
                    }
                }

            } else if (List.class.isAssignableFrom(value.getClass())) { // Indexed name
                List list = ((List) value);
                name = StringUtils.substringBeforeLast(name, "List");

                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    String indexedName = name + "[" + i + "]";
                    List<String> nestedNames = listNestedPropertyName(list.get(i));

                    for (String nestedName : nestedNames) {
                        nodeNameList.add(indexedName + "." + nestedName);
                    }
                }
            } else if (Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom(value.getClass())) { // Simple Value
                nodeNameList.add(name);
            } else { // Nested Value
                List<String> nestedNames = listNestedPropertyName(value);

                for (String nestedName : nestedNames) {
                    nodeNameList.add(name + "." + nestedName);
                }
            }
        }

        return nodeNameList;
    }
}
```

And then I iterate other those names to retrieve property value and then set them in the Map.

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

MyPropertyUtils myPropertyUtils = new MyPropertyUtils();
List<String> names = myPropertyUtils.listNestedPropertyName(employee);
for (String name : names) {
    map.put(name, PropertyUtils.getNestedProperty(employee, name));
}
```

This work well for my use case. I simply had add an accessor in my source object for accessing the Map or the List with a conventional name (propertyName + "Map" or "List").

Maybe this could interest someone. Anyway, if there is something more obvious to do it, let me know.

Comment: `orika` can transform beans to maps and vice versa. Just a hint if someone looks for the same.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I just give a look at the project and it looks promising (not only considering the this specific question)