# Convert Hashmap with simple, indexed, nested, or combined type attributes as keys into a Java Bean

Tags: java, apache, reflection, javabeans

I am trying to convert a java bean to hashmap and  then later convert the hashmap to java bean. For converting Java Object to hashmap this post helped me.  [Convert a JavaBean to key/value Map with nested name using commons-beans BeanUtils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165861/convert-a-javabean-to-key-value-map-with-nested-name-using-commons-beans-beanuti)

Code below

```
    public class Ax {
    String axAttr;

    public String getAxAttr() {
        return axAttr;
    }

    public void setAxAttr(String axAttr) {
        this.axAttr = axAttr;
    }

    List<Bx> bxs;

    public List<Bx> getBxs() {
        return bxs;
    }

    public void setBxs(List<Bx> bxs) {
        this.bxs = bxs;
    }
}

public class Bx {
    String bxAttr;

    public String getBxAttr() {
        return bxAttr;
    }

    public void setBxAttr(String bxAttr) {
        this.bxAttr = bxAttr;
    }

    List<Cx> cxs = new ArrayList<Cx>();

    public List<Cx> getCxs() {
        return cxs;
    }

    public void setCxs(List<Cx> cxs) {
        this.cxs = cxs;
    }
}

public class Cx {
    String cxAttr;

    public String getCxAttr() {
        return cxAttr;
    }

    public void setCxAttr(String cxAttr) {
        this.cxAttr = cxAttr;
    }

    List<String> items;

    public List<String> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<String> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

below is the key value-pairs stored in the `HashMap`

> axAttr --> axString
>   bxs[0].bxAttr --> bxString
>   bxs[0].cxs[0].cxAttr --> cxString
>   bxs[0].cxs[0].items[0] --> One
>   bxs[0].cxs[0].items[1] --> Two
>   bxs[0].cxs[0].items[2] --> Three

I stored these key values in `DB` and later retrieve them and want to convert to Java Bean again. But for converting the same `HashMap` to Java object with the help of `propertyUtilsbean` I am getting `NullPointerException.`

This is how I executed:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Ax ax = new Ax();
        ax.setAxAttr("axString");

        Bx bx = new Bx();
        bx.setBxAttr("bxString");

        Cx cx = new Cx();
        cx.setCxAttr("cxString");

        List<Bx> bxs = new ArrayList<Bx>();
        ax.setBxs(bxs);
        ax.getBxs().add(bx);

        List<Cx> cxs = new ArrayList<Cx>();
        bx.setCxs(cxs);
        bx.getCxs().add(cx);


        List<String> xs = new ArrayList<String>();
        cx.setAxs(xs);

        cx.getAxs().add(new String("One"));
        cx.getAxs().add(new String("Two"));
        cx.getAxs().add(new String("Three"));


        MyPropertyUtils myPropertyUtils = new MyPropertyUtils();

        Map map = new HashMap();
        for (String name :  myPropertyUtils.listNestedPropertyName(ax)) {
            map.put(name, PropertyUtils.getNestedProperty(ax, name));
        }

        Ax axNew = new Ax();

        Set<Entry> set = map.entrySet();


        for (Entry entry :set) {
            BeanUtils.setProperty(axNew, entry.getKey().toString(), entry.getValue().toString());
        }



    }
```

Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getIndexedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:507)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getIndexedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:410)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:768)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:846)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.setProperty(BeanUtilsBean.java:903)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.setProperty(BeanUtils.java:456)
    at com.wavecrest.aspect.Test1.main(Test1.java:57)
```

Any suggestions are accepted:

Comment: Post your code and Exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BeanUtils` don't create objects instances for you inside `axNew` instance. So, calling

```
BeanUtils.setProperty(axNew, "bxs[0].cxs[0].cxAttr", "Some value");
```

Means "Get first element of 'bxs' collection, then get first element of it and then update the 'cxAttr' property of this object". But `bxs` property of `axNew` is null at this moment, which causes `NullPointerException`.

You need to initialize your objects with empty objects and only then you will be able to update their properties with `setProperty` method, e.g.:

```
axNew.setBxs(new ArrayList<Bx>());
axNew.getBsx().add(new Bx());
// should works fine
BeanUtils.setProperty(axNew, "bxs[0].bxAttr", "Some value");
```

I would also add that it is not the best way to store objects with complex hierarchy inside DB. There are other more useful methods of serialization:

- ORM
- Conversion to XML/JSON
- Java Serialization
- etc.

Comment: hi mudalov, Thanks for the inputs. i understand that this is not the best way to store objects.

Comment: hi mudalov, Thanks for the inputs. i understand that this is not the best way to store objects. ORM is not feasible because we dont have information of the metadata of these objects. And using xml format doest not allow to query db to get statistics related to the objects stored. same with serialization also. hence storing objects as key value-pairs in db. and regarding the initialization of list i have that in my mind, just wanted to know if beanutils provides any other simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert a java bean to a hash map such that the map's keys are the bean's property names. For nested beans you could have property Path keys like "proprty1.property2".
If this fits the bill, I got a solution for you with my juffrou-reflect library. Hope it helps.